# Decrease opacity of current slide form 1 to 0 while transition

Tags: javascript, opacity

I have javascript code that increases the opacity of an incoming slide slowly. Now I want it to decrease the opacity of the current slide while transitioning.

Here is my code:

```
let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
var current = 0;

function cls(){
    slide[current].display='none';
}
function next(){
    cls();
    if(current === slide.length-1) current =-1 ;
    current++;
    slide[current].style.display = 'block';
    slide[current].style.opacity = 0.3;

    var x = 0.3;
    var intX = setInterval(function(){
        x+=0.1;
        slide[current].style.opacity = x;
        if(x >= 1) {
            clearInterval(intX);
            x = 0.1;
        }
    });

}
function prev(){
    cls();
    if(current === 0) current = slide.length;
    current--;

    slide[current].style.display = 'block';
    slide[current].style.opacity = 0.4;

    var x = 0.4;
    var intX = setInterval(function(){
        x+=0.1;
        slide[current].style.opacity = x;
        if(x >= 1) {
            clearInterval(intX);
            x = 0.4;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: can't you use CSS for this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just don't do `slide[current].display='none';` straight away in `cls()`, but use the same animation technique that you used for the incoming slides?